# cannot login into Frugalware Linux

Tags: linux, login

I just installed Frugalware Linux as a virtual machine. I entered the root password, created a new user (and password) and after it restarted I entered the username and the password and I cannot login. No error message, no hint.

Can anyone help me? Are there any requirement in the password (it should contain a number, letter, caps...?)

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to the password, except that it may not be empty (there are hacks around this - see below).

You should check `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd` and see if the user was actually created. If it was, blank out the password field (the really long part between two colons that's just a bunch of numbers and letters) and log in.